# Flutter doesn't run when cloud_functions: ^4.3.2 is on pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Already ran the following commands flutter clean, flutter pub get, flutter run and in addition to that have deleted multiple times the hosted cache folder.

I haven't seen any solutions and I believe I'm using the latest flutter version of the app. Also, when removing the cloud_function package from the pubspec.yaml the flutter app is able to build itself without any problems. Also I'm currently on the Blaze Firebase plan which enables me to use cloud functions.

## Error Message

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_functions'.
> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\{me}\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_functions-4.3.2\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':cloud_functions' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':cloud_functions' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

## pubspec.yaml (depenencies)

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.6
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  flutter_spinbox: ^0.13.0
  go_router: ^8.0.1
  firebase_core: ^2.13.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.5.3
  firebase_auth: ^4.4.2
  flutter_login: ^4.1.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  http: ^0.13.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.2.2
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.2.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11
  cloud_functions: ^4.3.2
```

## android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.mobile"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.chanator.mobile"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```